# Logs / stacktraces from abp.io Blazor app

Tags: .net, blazor, abp

Is there any way to check logs or stacktraces from a Blazor web app? I am trying to learn abp, and all I got is internal error. I have been trying to looking for logs or something, but finds nothing. Guess much of the errors are at the client side?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you refer to errors occur in the server side by *internal error*.

You can check Http.Api.Host **logs.txt** file under the `Logs` folder.